# AS2 TweenLite : using TintPlugin

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, tint, gsap

I have a problem with the TweenLite Tint Plugin in AS2.
Is there a way to decrease the alpha color ?

For instance :

> TweenLite.to ( mc, 1, { **tint : 0x586AB4**, blurFilter : { blurX : BLUR_FILTER, blurY : BLUR_FILTER }, dropShadowFilter : { blurX : BLUR_X, blurY : BLUR_Y, distance : SHADOW_DISTANCE, strength : SHADOW_STRENGTH, angle : SHADOW_ANGLE } } );

The "alpha" attribute must not be use because it only modifies the global movieclip "alpha".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TintPlugin.as seems to ignore alpha.

Do you mean the tint's alpha ? as in the amount of tint ?

Would you get the result you want by using the [ColorTransformPlugin](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/ColorTransformPlugin.html) with **tint** and **tintAmount** ?

e.g.

```
TweenLite.to ( mc, 1, { colorTransform:{tint:0x586AB4, tintAmount:0.5},blurFilter : { blurX : BLUR_FILTER, blurY : BLUR_FILTER }, dropShadowFilter : { blurX : BLUR_X, blurY : BLUR_Y, distance : SHADOW_DISTANCE, strength : SHADOW_STRENGTH, angle : SHADOW_ANGLE } } );
```

Comment: This works perfectly with the ColorTransformPlugin !
Thank you !